# Visual Studio 2022 XAML designer not showing images used as static resources

Tags: wpf, image, xaml, resources, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to start a new WPF project using the VS resource file to handle images.
I've made a window with a background image which is showing at runtime but I can't see it at design time.
Since I have to work with adding controls based on the image layout I'd like to see it in the designer.

This is my configuration:

-Image relative path is Images\SfondoBase.png, build action is "Resource"
-In the app xaml I have:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Other merged dictionaries -->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="SfondoBase" UriSource="Images/SfondoBase.png" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

-Main window's main grid has:

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource SfondoBase}" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
```

Right now I'm just seeing a white background which gets right when the application is launched.

Comment: here's accepted answer to problem similar to yours https://stackoverflow.com/a/76276574/10706024. Based on this I'd say You have two options, either declare the BitmapImage in separate ResourceDictionary, or add it as a Resource locally to the View.